# Displaying Gridview from the input matching multiple conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, sql-server-2008, gridview

How to display a GridView from database matching either one of the two conditions. I have 3 input TextBoxes. First condition is to display based on the 1st TextBox value and the second condition is to display based on all the three TextBoxes. My conditions are:

1.`select * from CG_TPO_GOV_EventDetails where EventName='Event Name 1'`

2.`select * from CG_TPO_GOV_EventDetails where EventName='Event Name 1' and StartDate='2011-11-11' and EndDate='2012-11-11'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Write SQL Query (i prefer stored procedure ), then Handle the Situation  like this,  and don't use `SELECT * from` , use only whatever column you needed,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SomeProcudereName
@EventName Nvacrchar(500),
@startDate DATETIME=NULL,
@EndDate DATETIME =NULL
AS 
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1  1 from  CG_TPO_GOV_EventDetails where EventName=@EventName)
    BEGIN
        IF @startDate IS  NULL AND @EndDate IS NULL 
         BEGIN
             select yourColumns from CG_TPO_GOV_EventDetails where EventName=@EventName -- 1st condition
         END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
             select yourColumns from CG_TPO_GOV_EventDetails where EventName=@EventName and StartDate<@EndDate  and EndDate >=@EndDate  -- do for 2'nd COndition 
        END   
    END
    ELSE
     BEGIN
         // No Events Found 
     END 

END
```

for checking between date, you can refer this link , which tells very clearly [Selecting Data between Dates](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Date_Range_WHERE_Clause_Simplification)

then You use this result to bind your textbox, with dataset

Comment: i just gave pseudocode, he can replace his code in the place of comments, atleast he can do that